# Typescript Generic Array of Interfaces

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a problem with more advanced Generic types in TypeScript.

What I want to do is an array of data where the `data` itself controlled by the `type` like:

```js
[
 {
  type: "T1",
  content: number,
 },
 {
  type: "T2",
  values: {
   id: number,
   ...
  }
 }
]
```

I kinda get stacked after describing the available types like:

```js
enum DataType {
 T1 = "t1",
 T2 = "t2"
}
```

So the result must look kinda like this, I guess:

```js
interface DataGeneric<T> {
 [T extends DataType.T1]: { content: number },
 [T extends DataType.T2]: { values: { id: number, ... } },
} ???

interface Data<T extends DataType = any(?)> extends DataGeneric<T>{
 type: DataType,
 // and all the other fields are generic from T = DataType
}
const someData: Data[] | undefined = fetchData();

// suggesting that the `type` of element[1] is "t2"
// and VSCode suggestions works correctly too,
// consider that there is an object-field `values` with `id` key
someData[1].values.id
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered a discriminated union instead of a generic? See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions

Comment: It definitely looks like you want a discriminated union instead of generic, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wR9EnW).  If that code meets your needs I could maybe write up an answer.  If not, please let me know what's missing.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, it is! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're checking an object's `type` property against a string or number [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html) to discriminate what type of data the rest of the object is holding, then you probably want to use a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) instead of generics.  That's basically a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) where the members of the union have a common *discriminant* key.  In your case it could look like this:

```
enum DataType {
  T1 = "t1",
  T2 = "t2"
}

type Data =
  { type: DataType.T1, content: number } |
  { type: DataType.T2, values: { id: number } }
```

Then when you have a value `data` of type `Data`, you can check its `type` property and the compiler knows that it should narrow `data` to the right member of the union:

```
declare const someData: Data[] | undefined;

if (someData) {
  someData.forEach(data => {
    if (data.type === DataType.T1) {
      data.content.toFixed();
    } else {
      data.values.id.toFixed();
    }
  })
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAIghgFzgFQJ4AdhQN4CgpTICMUAvFAEQJEUA0+hATGZQoxbgL664IZbwkZBtih9MALliIU-AHTFaUAMYB7EAlAIp4CACNgAJyicoAHxFj+UwbMwLGSgG5wANmGABnKaICWAEx1IA2NTbh5-YGVXOEMsNRBPBChPVQhgWxsZAG0AXXMoMBBIgDNfEGB-AG4eXxKoAApU9NsAShwGZoyZORLVQwBROGUACwb-GTIAPg6CAjrGiaQ5cSxSdekkNHtidrw5uaW4OQTNDRXVADFfAA9Khtaag9NgV08sfYOoI7kXdy85AELtc7v4Hk85twCJxWlweEA)